# glVertexAttribPointer trouble (OpenGL 3.x forward-compatible context)

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

By modern standards, the preferred way of rendering polygon meshes seems to involve the use of [Vertex Buffer Objects](https://web.archive.org/web/20160818093156/https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object) in conjunction with index buffers (ultimately drawn by calls to `glDrawElements()`), which is exactly why I'm trying to wrap my head around these concepts. Also, I insist on using `glVertexAttribPointer()` instead of the [deprecated](https://web.archive.org/web/20160701022445/https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Deprecation) `glVertexPointer()`, `glNormalPointer()` etc.

I'm using a custom, *binary* 3d file format (a Wavefront .OBJ derivative), the contents of which can be more or less directly `memcpy()`'d to a vertex array. Here's how I've declared my `vertex` structure:

```
   typedef struct vertex_ {

            float vx,vy,vz;
            float nx,ny,nz;
            float padding[2];  // align to 32 bytes 
   
   } vertex;
```

The `loadBObj()` function returns an *index buffer* (implemented as a simple array of `unsigned short int`s), and fills up the vertex array with the associated vertex/normal data (the models used all have been exported to have *per-vertex-normals* for a smoother shading result).

```
indices = loadBObj("pharaoh.bobj", false, &VBOid);
```

The loading code itself is *verified to work appropriately.*

Now, what's also being done in `loadBObj()`is a new VBO is being created like so:

```
    glGenBuffers(1, VBOid);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, *VBOid);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertex)*vcount, &vertarray[0].vx, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

After`loadBObj()` is called, an *index buffer object* (probably shouldn't be referred to as such though) is created as follows:

```
    glGenBuffers(1, &IBOid);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBOid);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned short int)*qfcount*4, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

OK. When it comes to actually rendering the mesh, I've used the following code:

```
    #define BUFFER_OFFSET(i) ((char *)NULL + (i))
    ...
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOid);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(3*sizeof(float)));

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBOid);
    glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, qfcount*4, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
```

which results in an absolutely correct geometry, but the shading is not quite right:

- Here's an image of the model, rendered in **immediate** mode:

[img http://i44.tinypic.com/i36zcg.png](http://i44.tinypic.com/i36zcg.png)

- here's one produced by the program described above:

[image: img2]

Is there something funny going on in my VBO handling?

Comment: Run it under gDEBugger, or something similar, and verify all the data in the VBO is correct. If it is, time to check shaders. Also, `GL_QUADS` is deprecated and gone from the core profile.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: alright, I've now thoroughly checked the contents of the VBO (gDEBugger = _fantabulous_ utility btw, cheers), and it seems ok. Now, what exactly do you mean by "checking shaders"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using shaders? You're only supposed to use glVertexAttribPointer with shaders, and you have to explicitly tell it which attrib array goes with which input variable. (glGetAttribLocation/glBindAttribLocation).

If you're using fixed pipeline you have to stick to glVertexPointer/glNormalPointer.

Comment: tested: the `glVertexPointer` / `glNormalPointer` equivalent yields a similar result. In fact, even if I initialized the normal vector components with zeroes / random data, the result is unchanged. I've been referring to the [OpenGL wiki VBO examples page](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/VBO_-_just_examples), which does indeed mention setting up a shader: "Also, we aren't using shaders but you must setup a shader and setup the binding for your vertex attributes to your shader for things to work." For shading similar to the immediate mode pic, what kind of a shader program would I use?

Comment: @elmov Its quite a bit more complicated than I can go into here, but I'm sure you can find many examples searching online for how to write shaders and how to implement lighting and shading.

Comment: +1 When he doesn't use shaders, that's exactly his problem. The reason it works for the position attribute is, that (at least prior to GL 3 or in compatibility mode) the generic vertex attribute 0 is an alias for the builtin `glVertex` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your normals are not passed through correctly

This is probably caused by the fact that you should have

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

Since you are specifying both 0 and 1 pointers. (currently you only have the first line)

Comment: - adding the line `glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);` seems to have had no effect whatsoever. Thanks for the suggestion, though; I'm going to leave it there regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I think what could have happened here is that the triangle* are reversed. You could test that just by swapping each first with each third vertex.

- Since you're using quads, that's clearly not the error. But you can try swapping each second with each third vertex.